# test if two variables holds some data javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I define variables from two input fields - and wants to test if something was actually entered in both fields and then break if more than one field is filled.

I think the 'undefined' tricks me when setting the var's to .value - even though they don't contain data.

```
                var value1 = document.getElementById('filegroup').value;
                var value2 = document.getElementById('new_filegroup').value;
                if(value1 !== undefined && value2 !== undefined )
                {
                    alert("You must only fill one filegroup!")
                    return false;
                }
```

Right now I'm being alerted even though I don't fill in anything.

Comment: `if (value1 != "" && ...`

Comment: `if(typeof value !== "undefined"`

Comment: The value will not be undefined so the check makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `document.getElementById('filegroup')` is a form input of some type, the value will return a empty string when there is no value. Try:

```
var value1 = document.getElementById('filegroup').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('new_filegroup').value;

if(value1 && value2) { // checks both values have something
    alert("Both values have something")
}

if(value1 || value2) { // checks for at least one value
    alert("one of them does")
}
```

N.B. if the values **do** come from a input, then a value of `0` will be a string, and seen as truthy. However the number `0` will be falsey.

Comment: `if (value1)` would fail if the user entered `0`. Need to check for empty explicitly.

Comment: Actually no, because `value1` or `value2` will be the _string_ `'0'` which evaluates to true: `!!'0'` returns `true`. Just the same with whitespace characters: `!!' '` returns `true`. Only the empty string returns `false`.

Comment: updated my answer. I guess your both right as I'm assuming that its a input field but it might not be, not sure what it could be though to provide a value of type number as even a input type='number' returns a string

Comment: AFAIK no `HTMLelement.value` returns anything other than a string.

Comment: Thats certainly how the spec has it: `interface HTMLInputElement, attribute DOMString value;`

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I am mistaken. I think I'm just gun-shy around possible numeric inputs (and the possibility it was `parseInt` -ed or `parseFloat` -ed

Comment: FYI `typeof document.getElementById("progress").value` would be `Number`

Comment: `if(value1 && value2)` was the correct way to check in my case. I don't see the logic but it works ;)

Comment: Try theses [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). they'll make the whole thing a bit clearer Re: the logic in if (value1) etc

Comment: @atmd exactly - In my mind the `var value1 =` and `var value2 =` defines the var's (even though they don't contain any string). My logic therefore tells me that `if (value1 && value2)` should return true in all cases because the var's exists, and that I therefore need to check if they contain a string in some other way - But reality beats me ;)

Comment: if you did `var something;` then `something`, although declared is still `undefined`, because it has no value. `undefined` is a falsey value, so having `if (something)` will be false(y). if the variable didn't exist, then you'd get a `reference Error: [some var] is not defined`